# ¿Cuándo limpiar el buffer de entrada?

Tags: c, programación-bajo-nivel

¿Como sé cuando tengo que limpiar el **buffer de entrada**? Ya sé que lo tengo que hacer cuando no me deja ingresar más datos o simplemente me salta al proximo ingreso. Pero quiero teoría, lo tengo que limpiar cada vez que se ingresa un caracter/string? ¿Simplemente cuando hay strings? ¿O siempre?

Comment: De qué entrada es el buffer? Esto es Windows, Linux, RTOS? En general debería limpiarse luego de leerlo. Dependiendo de la aplicación también podría ser suficiente con sobrescribirlo independientemente de si ya fue leído o no.

Answer (score 0):

Mira la [lista de funciones de entrada](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Cada una tiene su descripción y explica su funcionamiento.

Normalmente usarás `scanf` y `gets`.

Lo que sucede es que estas funciones *detienen* la consola y es necesario presionar **Enter** para que el programa continúe. Esto deja un salto de línea en el buffer de entrada.

Esto por sí solo no es problemático.

Para entenderlo mejor, tengamos en cuenta lo que la documentación tiene para decirnos de [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> All conversion specifiers other than `[`, `c`, and `n` consume and discard all leading whitespace characters (determined as if by calling [isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace)) before attempting to parse the input. These consumed characters do not count towards the specified maximum field width.

Traducido al español, se consumen todos los caracteres de espacio en blanco (también saltos de línea) antes de la conversión de acuerdo al especificador. Excepto si el especificador fue `[`, `c` o `n`.

Y la función [`gets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) lee hasta el primer salto de línea sin descartar espacio en blanco previo.

---

La conclusión es que si usas `scanf` con un especificador diferente a `[`, `c` o `n` y luego `gets` u otro `scanf` con `[`, `c` o `n` necesitarás descartar el espacio en medio.

Hay diferentes formas de hacerlo. Una de ellas es con `getchar()` y la otra es con `scanf(" ")`, que solo lo consume si es necesario.

Si sabes que vas a leer un número y un carácter, una forma más conveniente de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
scanf(" %d %c", &numero, &caracter);
```

De esta manera descarta el espacio previo al número y el que se pudiera encontrar entre el número y el carácter.