# Buffer de entrada en C

Tags: c

Como estan?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pais {
  char nombre[40];
  int cantidad;
};


void cargoDatos(){

  struct pais paises[3];

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    printf("Nombre pais %d: ",i+1);
    fgets(paises[i].nombre,sizeof(paises[i].nombre),stdin);
    strtok(paises[i].nombre,"\n");

    printf("Cantidad de habitantes en %s : ",paises[i].nombre);
    scanf("%d",&paises[i].cantidad);
    
    <Aca Limpio Buffer>
 
  }
  for(int i = 0; i <3; i++){
    printf("%s --> %d\n",paises[i].nombre,paises[i].cantidad);
  }

}



int main(){

  printf("Bienvenido.\n\n");
  cargoDatos();
  


  return 0;
}
```

Yo siempre limpie el buffer con **while(getchar () == '\n' && getchar() == EOF);**
Pero ahora esto no me funciona como quiero. Y lo que si me funciona es simplemente poner **getchar()**. Alguno me puede explicar por favor porque uno me funciona y el otro no?

Comment: No sé qué pinta el `EOF` en tu ejemplo. Las siglas de `EOF` provienen del inglés, que significa **E**nd **O**f **F**ile, por lo que se utiliza como "flag" para saber cuándo no hay más información que obtener de un fichero. La función `getchar()` simplemente va a esperar que insertes un carácter, pero no lo va a guardar en ningún lado, por lo que eso hace que "limpie" tu buffer

Comment: Hace poco dí una respuesta sobre [cuándo limpiar el buffer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/598632/169744) y algunas formas de no tener que limpiarlo manualmente. Creo que te servirá.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque hayas declarado `EOF` para representar el final del archivo, la condición que has creado está intentando leer dos caracteres:

```
getchar() == '\n' && getchar() == EOF
```

Cuando se hace la primera llamada a `getchar()`, leerá el `'\n'` del buffer.
Luego viene la segunda llamada a `getchar()`, que leerá el siguiente carácter en el buffer, que es el carácter `'\n'` anterior.

Al usar `getchar()` dos veces, la segunda llamada a `getchar()` quedará esperando más entrada y, por lo tanto, bloqueará la ejecución. Ese es el problema en tu código.

Podría ser de esta manera

```
while ((caracter = getchar()) != EOF) { }
```

o de esta otra manera:

```
while ((caracter = getchar()) != '\n' && caracter != EOF) {}
```

*Ejemplo* : [**replit**](https://replit.com/@cardosource/limpiarBUFFER#main.c)

Comment: No será `&& caracter != EOF`?

Comment: si, habia cambiado la letra C, por caracter, pero no le hice caso al ultimo ejemplo cuando publiqué la respuesta... muchas gracias por avisarme