Problema al compilar 'C' en VSCode
No es como que no compile, sino que al procesar el programa, me pide los datos numericos, los escribe en el archivo, pero despues no me toma la frase, salta directamente al final del programa.
(Ya intente poniendo fflush() por todos lados pero tampoco funciona.
Mi compilador es GCC, descargado e instalado como en la demostracion oficial de Visual, no creo que el problema tenga que ver con eso. (por si lo quieren ver, segui exactamente estos pasos: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)
El programa fue corrido en otra PC y funciono sin problemas, evidentemente, es algo de la mia.
Dejo el codigo a continuacion:
    # include <stdio.h>
    # include <stdlib.h>
    # include <string.h>

    int main() {
        int num;
        char frase[50];
        FILE * pfile;

        pfile = fopen("Archivo_de_Escritura.txt", "w");
        if (pfile == NULL) {
            printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        do {
            printf("Introduce un numero por teclado: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            if (num != 0) {
                if ((num%2)==0) {
                    fprintf(pfile,"%d\n",num);
                }
            }
        } while (num!=0);
        printf("Introduce ahora una frase: ");
        gets(frase);
        fflush(stdin);
        fprintf(pfile, "%d\n%s\n",num,frase);

        fclose(pfile);
        rewind(pfile);

    return 0;
    }


PD: El codigo funciona bien en CodeBlocks.

sera porque lo estas ejecutando en una terminal powershell y no en una comun?

¿Puedes compilar tu código con "-Wall"? Esto mostrará todos los errores y advertencias. En VS2022, creo que gets() está en desuso y ni siquiera puedo encontrarlo en stdio.h  (Y gets() es malo porque no verifica la longitud del búfer en el que escribe)

@gbianchi Intente ejecutarlo tambien con (f8) si eso es a lo que te referis y tampoco funciona :(

@PeterM  He probado con 'fgets', tampoco compilo bien.

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Por qué en el segundo ciclo del algoritmo no acepta la funcion gets(name);?

No es un error de compilación y fflush(stdin) no sirve. Mira estas publicaciones https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/226494 https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/598632

Solucionado.
Se cambio el 2do fflush por un getchar. Ahora corre perfecto, muchas gracias!

Para solucionarlo debes de colocar el fflush(stdin); antes de colocar el gets.


Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
